# No "iOS Device" Option in Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm facing a problem with Xcode. I developed an App which I want to submit to the App Store. But I need the app archive, and everything i find on the web tells me to choose "iOS Device" as a device for build. But the option is not available.
I have a valid Provisioning profile and developer account.
Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: choose _Generic iOS Device_ then you can _Archive_ the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to pick "Generic iOS device" when you are building your app for archiving and submitting for review.

- You cannot "Run" the Generic iOS Device.
- Use this build setting only for building or archiving for ARM iOS devices.

Product > Archive

[image]

Comment: When i choose this option, Xcode shows me this error message :" A build only device cannot be used to run this target. No supported iOS devices are available. Connect a device to run your application or choose a simulated device as the destination."

Comment: You won't be able to *RUN* your app, but you should be able to create an archive with the generic device selected.

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry for noob question :P

Comment: You are clicking on run button , you will see archive option in debug menu this will create the ipa file that can be uploaded to app store.

Answer (score 0):

Genric ios device is equivalent of iOS device so you should use genric ios device option for archiving the project.